# Spring Boot says that JPA doesn't support custom isolation levels, but it seems like spring can do it

Tags: spring-boot

In spring boot's BasicBatchConfigurer there is a warning presented:

logger.warn("JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs");

However, I get the impression that this issue has been addressed: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11942

Is there a work around for this issue? Should I just be extending BatchConfigurer and implementing my own createJobRepository method? Should there be a change to spring boot code?

Comment: I still receive the warning message in Spring 4.2.4 although the JIRA (that you reference) states fix version 4.1 RC2.

Comment: The issue [SPR-11942](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11942) is related to the Spring Framework and not to Spring Boot. Moreover the warning message is not exactly the same. I think the warning you are facing is a different problem.